# Angular Firebase update code not executed inside snapshot foreach

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update my firebase database field with the following code:

```
//delete user token
delete_user_device_token() {
    let ref = this.afDatabase.database.ref("users/" + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid + "/chats");
    let groups = this.afDatabase.database.ref("users/" + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid + "/groups");
    let data = {};

    groups.once("value").then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(group => {
        data["groups/" + group.key + "/users/" + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid + "/device_token"] = null;
      })

      this.afDatabase.database.ref().update(data);
      console.log("1")
    })

    ref.once("value").then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(chat => {
        data["users/" + chat.key + "/chats/" + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid + "/user/device_token"] = null;
      })

      this.afDatabase.database.ref().update(data);
      console.log("2")
    })

    data["users/" + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid + "/device_token"] = null;
    console.log("3")
    return this.afDatabase.database.ref().update(data);
}
```

However, codes inside the foreach loop are not executed when I call:

```
this.firebaseProvider.delete_user_device_token().then(() => {
  //logout
  this.authProvider.logout().then(() => {
    //toaster
    this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'You have been logged out',
      duration: 3000
    }).present();
  });
});
```

Result in console log:

```
3
```

As you can see, only the last update inside delete_user_deivce_token works and I can confirm this inside the database, the code inside snapshot foreach are not executed, I've looked online and it seems I can fix this by using Promise.all, but I'm not sure how I can implement this within my code.

Comment: Do you want to see logs synchronously ("1" → "2" → "3") or in parallel ?

Comment: doesn’t really matter as long as they all gets executed, the problem I have now is that the foreach loops are never executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations with Firebase are async and return Promise, you need to handle it.

Example using async/await:

```
//delete user token
async delete_user_device_token() {
    let ref = this.afDatabase.database.ref("users/" + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid + "/chats");
    let groups = this.afDatabase.database.ref("users/" + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid + "/groups");
    let data = {};

    const foo1 = await groups.once("value");

      foo1.forEach(group => {
        data["groups/" + group.key + "/users/" + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid + "/device_token"] = null;
      })

      console.log("1")

    const foo2 = await ref.once("value");
      foo2.forEach(chat => {
        data["users/" + chat.key + "/chats/" + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid + "/user/device_token"] = null;
      })

      console.log("2")


    data["users/" + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid + "/device_token"] = null;
    console.log("3")
    return this.afDatabase.database.ref().update(data);
}
```

Output excepted:

```
1
2
3
```

You are doing several times the same update, is it really what you want to do ? You can update several nodes in one update.

Please add explanations if you want a cleanest answer.

Comment: I would like to update once for all, but couldn't get it to work with one update, that's why I've added update in the foreach loop

Comment: Then the last update should be suffisant, I updated my answer